# Is there a 5-7♭-1-4 chord?

Tags: chords, chord-theory, harmony, chord-progressions

I've encountered such a chord in a progression between a vi and IV and I couldn't quite figure out what it was supposed to be. I suppose it could be a v<sup>7</sup> with a doubly diminished fifth or a I<sup>7</sup> with an augmented third but I've never heard of either of those. What might one call such a chord?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be inclined to call it an applied chord (that is, a secondary dominant) of the IV chord, with one of two caveats.

Let's think of this in C to help explain it. The `vi` is A minor, and this `vi` moves to `IV`, or F major. The `5-♭7-1` are `G-B♭-C`, which can be ordered as `C-G-B♭` to show it's a `C7` chord with missing third (`E`). This `E` is then just replaced by an `F`.

And here's where theorists would differ. Some would just call this a `C7sus4` chord (as shown on a keyboard and in tab form [here](https://www.scales-chords.com/chord/guitar/C7sus4)) to show that the chordal third has been replaced by `4` (that's the `sus4` part). Others would say that the `4` is just what we call a non-chord tone; specifically, this `4` "anticipates" the resolution to the F chord (since F is `4`), thus we call that `4` an anticipation.

I'm not sure distinguishing between the two is all that important; labeling it is less important than understanding the logic of it. But, generally, I'd say this: if this is classical music, call the `4` an anticipation (thus it's a non-chord tone); if it isn't classical music, call it a `C7sus4`.

Comment: Does the chord even need a description? It sounds like the`G` is a passing note between the `A` of `iv` and the `F` of `VI`, and the `B♭` is a passing note between the `C` of `iv` and the `A` of `VI`.

Comment: @Gareth I largely agree. My only concern was that we'd have a passing tone `G`, a passing `B♭`, an anticipatory `F`, and an `E` held over from the previous chord. In this case I went with Occam's Razor and tried to have an explanation with as few non-chord tones as possible. (But I do think you're correct!)

Comment: @Gareth -  iv maybe should be IV;  VI maybe should be vi, and in key C, there's no F in VI...

Comment: @Tim I think Gareth had some dyslexia with his Roman numerals ;-)

Comment: @Tim Yeah, sorry I mixed up my 6 and 4. But other than that little mistake, I think my comment has some merit.

Comment: @Gareth - it has. However, a chord will need a description - or a name - in order to communicate it to others. Better than saying 'play 5, b7, 1 and 4'.

Comment: @Tim But surely it depends on the harmonic rhythm of the piece at the point the particular group of notes appears? If a passage had one or more instruments playing semiquavers, I wouldn't notate the chord at each note. Also, having played that particular sequence of notes now, that group of notes could equally be interpreted as an F major chord with a double appoggiatura resolving. Without context though it's hard to say.

Answer (score 2):

Before I saw Richard's answer, I was of the same opinion. Generally, I'd go for C7sus4, as it has all the components - C (root), Bb (m7), G (5) and F (sus4). If the 5 is at the bottom, it should be C7sus4/G (all obviously in key C).

I've seen it written as C11, although not totally convinced. Reasoning seems to be 7+4=11. Not too accurate, as there ought to be a maj3, and also 9th in there.